Convergence of sequence defined by successive exponentiation
Let $c\geq 0$ and define a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers inductively by $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=c^{a_n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. In other words;
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1\\
a_1 &=c\\
a_2 &= c^c \\
a_3 &= c^{c^c} \\
&\,\,\,\vdots
\end{align}
I'm wondering what can be said in general about the convergence of this sequence.
I believe (although I'm not quite sure) the question can be split into three subranges of the parameter $c$.

$c\in [1,\sqrt{2}]$. I already noted that in this case, the sequence is increasing and bounded (e.g. by 2), hence it must converge.

For $c\in[0,1)$, the sequence is not necessarily increasing, so the previous argument does not work here. Nor does it seem particularly easy to prove that it is a Cauchy sequence. However, after playing around with the numbers numerically, it seems that we have convergence in this range. Can we prove this?

For $c\in(\sqrt{2},\infty)$, numerical simulations suggest that the sequence diverges to infinity. Can we prove this?


Finally, the results do not seem to depend much on the initial condition $a_0=1$. Numerically I get similar results when I take $a_0$ to be essentially arbitrary. Can we prove independence of $a_0$ as well?

Try the google search "Exponentials Reiterated", the title of this paper. See also this list of references assembled by Ioannis Galidakis (I snail-mailed paper photocopies of these to him during 2002-2006).

If $c = 0$, then the sequence converges to $0$. In what follows, assume $c>0$.
The sequence satisfies $x_{n+1} = f_c(x_n)$ where
$$f_c(x) = e^{x \ln(c)}$$
In what follows, I'll assume that $x_0 > 0$ (you asked about $x_0 = 1$ but then also about other starting values).
Notice that for the sequence to possibly converge to some limit $\ell$, we must have $\ell = f_c(\ell)$, or equivalently, $g_c(\ell) = 1$ where $g_c(x) = f_c(x)/x$. Now studying the function $g_c(x) = \frac{f_c(x)}{x}$ turns out to be very helpful.
1. Case where $c > 1$
In this case, $g_c$ is decreasing from $0$ to $1/\ln(c)$ and then increasing. Therefore, it reaches a minimum at $1/\ln(c)$, and the minimum value is $e \ln(c)$. We must have $e \ln(c) \leq 1$ to have one or more possible limits, which gives $c \leq e^{1/e}$. Also, if $e \ln(c) > 1$, then $f_c(x) > x$ for all $x$, so that the sequence is increasing. We deduce that
If $c > e^{1/e}$, then $x_n$ diverges to infinity
Notice that $e^{1/e} \approx 1.44$ which is not too far from $\sqrt{2}$.
In the limit case where $c = e^{1/e}$, then there is exacly one solution to $f_c(\ell) = \ell$, which is given by $\ell = 1/\ln(c) = e$. Moreover, it is easy to show that $(x_n)_{n}$ is increasing if $x_0 \neq \ell$. Thus
If $c = e^{1/e}$, then $(x_n)_n$ diverges to infinity if $x_0 > e$ and converges to $e$ otherwise.
Finally if $1 < c < e^{1/e}$, there are two possible limits $\ell_1 < \ell_2$ satisfying $f_c(\ell_1) = \ell_1$ and $f_c(\ell_2) = \ell_2$. Moreover, $f_c(x) - x$ is negative for $x$ between $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ and positive otherwise. Since $f$ is increasing, it is also easy to show that if $x_0 \in [\ell_1,\ell_2]$, then $x_n$ stays there always. Therefore, $(x_n)$ is increasing if $x_0 < \ell_1$, decreasing if $x_0 \in (\ell_1,\ell_2)$, increasing if $x_0 > \ell_2$, and constant otherwise. The sequence therefore

converges to $\ell_1$ if $x_0 \in (0,\ell_2)$
converges to $\ell_2$ if $x_0 = \ell_2$
diverges to $\infty$ if $x_0 > \ell_2$.

2. Case where $c = 1$
This is not very interesting : $f_c$ is constant equal to $1$, so $(x_n)$ converges in all cases to $1$.
3. Case where $c<1$
Now $f_c$ is decreasing, and by the intermediate value theorem, there is exactly one $\ell$ such that $f_c(\ell) = \ell$. But convergence to this limit might be more difficult to study (for example, one could have ``convergence'' towards a cycle, as it seems to happen for very small values of $c$, or even maybe some chaotic behavior). Behavior like this happens for a well-studied sequence : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map
EDIT : here is a cobweb diagram (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) of the $100$ first terms of the sequence for $c = 0.001$ and $x_0 = 1$. The solid black line is the graph of $f_c$, the dashed line is $y = x$

And another one for $c = 1.3$, with $x_0 < \ell_1$ (blue), $x_0 \in (\ell_1,\ell_2)$ (red), and $x_0 > \ell_2$ (green).

